# add node azure to elasticsearch

Tags: azure, elasticsearch

I have two dedicated servers (host1 , host2) and I have installed elastic 2.1 in my two dedicated servers

in my config I have

host1

```
cluster.name: myclus
node.name: node-1
network.host: ip address 1
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1","ip address 2"]
```

in my host2

```
cluster.name: myclus
node.name: node-2
network.host: ip address 2
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1","ip address 1"]
```

and it's working

But when I want add my cloud azure on my architecture 
I have two IP addresses in my azure cloud (local ip ,public ip)
my configuration is

```
cluster.name: myclus
node.name: node-3
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1","ip address 1","ip address 2"]
```

I have this error

```
[2015-12-09 00:19:55,617][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to install syscall filter: syscall filtering not supported for OS: 'Windows Server 2012 R2'
[2015-12-09 00:19:56,133][INFO ][node                     ] [node-cloud] version[2.1.0], pid[3516], build[72cd1f1/2015-11-18T22:40:03Z]
[2015-12-09 00:19:56,133][INFO ][node                     ] [node-cloud] initializing ...
[2015-12-09 00:19:56,461][INFO ][plugins                  ] [node-cloud] loaded [], sites [head]
[2015-12-09 00:19:56,524][INFO ][env                      ] [node-cloud] using [1] data paths, mounts [[(C:)]], net usable_space [115.8gb], net total_space [126.6gb], spins? [unknown], types [NTFS]
[2015-12-09 00:20:01,133][INFO ][node                     ] [node-cloud] initialized
[2015-12-09 00:20:01,133][INFO ][node                     ] [node-cloud] starting ...
[2015-12-09 00:20:01,664][INFO ][transport                ] [node-cloud] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
[2015-12-09 00:20:01,696][INFO ][discovery                ] [node-cloud] proveille/WuNr5mY9RVO6XsRWtkcYdQ
[2015-12-09 00:20:05,085][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [node-cloud] failed to send join request to master [{node-1}{cxzF7IYWSCCY2E58wKX_Ow}{ip adress 1}{ip adress 1:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[node-1][ip adress 1:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: ConnectTransportException[[node-cloud][127.0.0.1:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[Connexion refusée: /127.0.0.1:9300]; ]
[2015-12-09 00:20:08,327][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [node-cloud] failed to send join request to master [{node-1}{cxzF7IYWSCCY2E58wKX_Ow}{ip adress 1}{ip adress 1:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[node-1][ip adress 1:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: ConnectTransportException[[node-cloud][127.0.0.1:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[Connexion refusée: /127.0.0.1:9300]; ]
[2015-12-09 00:20:11,547][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [node-cloud] failed to send join request to master [{node-1}{cxzF7IYWSCCY2E58wKX_Ow}{ip adress 1}{ip adress 1:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[node-1][ip adress 1:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: ConnectTransportException[[node-cloud][127.0.0.1:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[Connexion refusée: /127.0.0.1:9300]; ]
[2015-12-09 00:20:14,761][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [node-cloud] failed to send join request to master [{node-1}{cxzF7IYWSCCY2E58wKX_Ow}{ip adress 1}{ip adress 1:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[node-1][ip adress 1:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: ConnectTransportException[[node-cloud][127.0.0.1:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[Connexion refusée: /127.0.0.1:9300]; ]
[2015-12-09 00:20:17,979][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [node-cloud] failed to send join request to master [{node-1}{cxzF7IYWSCCY2E58wKX_Ow}{ip adress 1}{ip adress 1:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[node-1][ip adress 1:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: ConnectTransportException[[node-cloud][127.0.0.1:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[Connexion refusée: /127.0.0.1:9300]; ]
[2015-12-09 00:20:21,208][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [node-cloud] failed to send join request to master [{node-1}{cxzF7IYWSCCY2E58wKX_Ow}{ip adress 1}{ip adress 1:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[node-1][ip adress 1:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: ConnectTransportException[[node-cloud][127.0.0.1:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[Connexion refusée: /127.0.0.1:9300]; ]
[2015-12-09 00:20:24,433][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [node-cloud] failed to send join request to master [{node-1}{cxzF7IYWSCCY2E58wKX_Ow}{ip adress 1}{ip adress 1:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[node-1][ip adress 1:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: ConnectTransportException[[node-cloud][127.0.0.1:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[Connexion refusée: /127.0.0.1:9300]; ]
[2015-12-09 00:20:25,343][INFO ][node                     ] [node-cloud] stopping ...
[2015-12-09 00:20:25,389][INFO ][node                     ] [node-cloud] stopped
[2015-12-09 00:20:25,389][INFO ][node                     ] [node-cloud] closing ...
[2015-12-09 00:20:25,405][INFO ][node                     ] [node-cloud] closed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
failed to send join request to master [{node-1}{cxzF7IYWSCCY2E58wKX_Ow}{ip adress 1}{ip adress 1:9300}], 
reason [RemoteTransportException[[node-1][ip adress 1:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]];
nested: ConnectTransportException[[node-cloud][127.0.0.1:9300] connect_timeout[30s]];
```

shows node-1 cannot communicate with node-cloud, the reason probably is the 9300 port on node-3 server isn't exposed. You can test it using the following statement:

```
telnet node-3-ip 9300
```

if the terminal shows:

```
Trying node-3-ip...
Connected to node-3-ip.
Escape character is '^]'
```

indicates that the 9300 port on node-3 server is exposed, but if the terminal shows:

```
Trying node-3-ip...
telnet: connect to address node-3-ip Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

indicates the 9300 port is not exposed. In this case, login to node-3 server and modify iptables:

```
 vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

add the following statement:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9300 -j ACCEPT
```

and restart iptables:

```
service iptables restart
```

finaly restart elasticsearch and try again.